# Riddle Poem Four

Tags: pattern

Here's a quick little puzzle I thought up. If you want to be really creative write out a last line for me, otherwise let me know what the sequence is and what comes next.

> As a side note, length requirements for posting makes it difficult to send these smaller puzzles.. perhaps that should be addressed?

My pattern is simple, 
But it might not be what you think. 
Look very closely, 
And you will find the missing link. 
Just beware! 
You could be this puzzle’s hero, 
But.. 
My answer is not zero.

Comment: Just a note, hero and zero rhyme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer:

> The poem's pattern seems to alternate word count in decreasing order. From the start, every other line counts down from 4, while the other counts down from 8. So it looks like 4, 8, 3, 7, 2, 6, 1, 5.  Continuing this pattern the next # would be 0 or, no words. But the last line says the answer is not 0. So I'm guessing the pattern is going to loop back around. Meaning, the next lines would be 9,4,8,3, etc. in word length to continue and begin repeating the existing pattern. So, the next line will be 9 words in length.

Comment: It's close enough to right. However, there's a reason why it never hits 0, which isn't arbitrary and relies on an equation.